# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' in linux mint 20.2 PHP8

Tags: php, pdo

In my linux mint installation i tra use symfony internal server for developing in PHP8 `symfony server:start` but this produce error `An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver` becuse this try connet to MariaDB.

```
php -v

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
```

pdo extensions in php.ini is enabled. I try remove and install php8, but this produce same error

```
grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php/8.0 | grep -E "extension(\s+)?="
```

```
/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini:extension=pdo_mysql
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xsl.ini:extension=xsl.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/simplexml.ini:extension=simplexml.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/iconv.ini:extension=iconv.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/gettext.ini:extension=gettext.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mbstring.ini:extension=mbstring.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/readline.ini:extension=readline.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini:extension=sysvshm.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/exif.ini:extension=exif.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/ftp.ini:extension=ftp.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/shmop.ini:extension=shmop.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/intl.ini:extension=intl.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini:extension=tokenizer.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xmlreader.ini:extension=xmlreader.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/opcache.ini:zend_extension=opcache.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini:extension=pdo_mysql.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini:extension=fileinfo.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/ctype.ini:extension=ctype.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sockets.ini:extension=sockets.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/phar.ini:extension=phar.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/dom.ini:extension=dom.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xml.ini:extension=xml.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini:extension=sysvsem.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/posix.ini:extension=posix.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini:extension=mysqlnd.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/ffi.ini:extension=ffi.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini:extension=mysqli.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini:extension=sysvmsg.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/calendar.ini:extension=calendar.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/pdo.ini:extension=pdo.so
/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xmlwriter.ini:extension=xmlwriter.so
/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini:extension=pdo_mysql
```

Comment: No I add some code to question

Comment: it looks for pdo_mysql in /usr/lib/php/20200930/ folder, but grep command says its installed in another directory. Long story short: create a symbolic link from /etc/php/8.0/mods-available to /usr/lib/php/20200930/ folder. Its just a test workaround.